# find the each number of 4 digit of user input and count it using recursion

Tags: c++

I have with my code. This is about recursion. I have to create function `digitAppear( int findDigit, int value)` where `value` is the user input, and `findDigit` is single digit number ranging from 0 to 9. The function read user input and return each digit number from the user input and count how many times each digit number occurs in the user input. For example, if I type 1234 then the output say 1 appear 1 time, 2 appear 1 time and so on (I hope my explanation is clear) The problem is the only run once and can only return 1 value.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int countOccurence(int, int);

int main()
{

    int findDig;
    int value;
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a positive number: " << endl;
    cin >> value;
    cout << "The value is " << value << endl;

    while ((value < 0) || (value > 9999))
    {
        cout << "Invalid value. Please try again!" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a positive number: " << endl;
        cin >> value; //you need this here, otherwise you're going to be stuck in an infinite loop after the first invalid entry
    }

    //process the value
    for (findDig = 0; findDig < 9; findDig++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << cout << "the " << findDig << "appear in digit " << value <<  " is " << countOccurence(findDig, value) << " times" << endl;
    }


    //countOccurance(findDig, value);
    //cout
}

int countOccurence(int findDig, int value)
{
    int n = value;

    while( n > 10 )
    {
         int a = n / 10; //eliminate the right most integer from the rest
         int aa = n % 10; //separate the right most integer from the rest
         int b = a / 10; //eliminate the second integer from the rest
         int bb = a % 10; //separate the second integer from the rest
         int c = b / 10; // eliminate the third integer from the rest
         int cc = b % 10; //separate the third integer from the rest

         for (findDig = 0; findDig < 9; findDig++)
         {
             int i = 0;
             if (findDig == aa) // see if the findDigit value is equal to single digit of b;
             {
                 i += 1;
             } else
             {   
                 i += 0; 
             }
             return i;

             if (findDig == bb)
             {
                 i += 1;
             } else
             {   
                 i += 0; 
             }
             return i;

             if (findDig == cc)
             {
                 i += 1;
             } else
             {   
                 i += 0; 
             }
             return il;
         }
    }

}
```

The problem is my function `countOccurence()` doesn't seems right. I wonder if there a way to do it. I have been stuck with this for days and I really appreciate your input, thank you.

Comment: And where is there the recursion?

Comment: With a *'single digit number ranging from 0 to 9'* you're going to have a trouble: how will you recognize how many zeros user typed if the input was, say "000"...?

Comment: then the program output will be **The number 0 in digit 0000 appear 4 times**

Comment: Here is the instructions. _Write a recursive C++ function int countOccurance(int findDig,  int value). The parameter ‘findDig’  is a single digit between 0 and 9.  The parameter ‘value’ is an int of one or more digits. This recursive function returns the number of times ‘findDig’ occurs in the ‘value’.  Write a short C++ main which reads in two int values and calls this function._ the countOccurance() function itself throw me off. In this code i just limit my code up to 4 digit to start the code to minimize compile or runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

To use recursion, you must think about the problem in a different way.

The easiest way of thinking about how you could incorporate recursion into the function is the process of 'peeling off' each number.

A very simple way of doing this is by looking at the first/last digit in the number, compute that, then call itself on the remainder of the number.

Hopefully you can figure out the code from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that function digitAppear itself has to be recursive then it can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

size_t digitAppear( int findDigit, int value )
{
    return ( std::abs( value ) % 10u == std::abs( findDigit ) ) +
           ( ( value /= 10 ) ? digitAppear( findDigit, value ) : 0 );
}


int main() 
{
    int i = 0;

    for ( int x : { 0, 11111, 1234, 34343 } )
    {
        std::cout << "There are " << digitAppear( i, x )
                  << " digit " << i
                  << " in number " << x
                  << std::endl;

        ++i;                  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
There are 1 digit 0 in number 0
There are 5 digit 1 in number 11111
There are 1 digit 2 in number 1234
There are 3 digit 3 in number 34343
```

Of course you may rewrite function main as you like for example that it would count each digit in a number.

Comment: That's kind of the idea. let say my user input is 1234. then the program output will be `The number 1 appear in digit 1234 is 1 time. The number 2 appear in digit 1234 is 1 time. The number 3 appear in digit 1234 is 1 time. The number 4 appear in digit 1234 is 1 time.' If i put 9999, then the program output will be 'The number 9 appear in digit 9999 is 4 time`. That's why i have problem to do the remainder and division using the recursion. The example on the book is very simple and its not really help